# Node.js, bitfinex-api-node: How-to set-up correctly to process data from the websocket-connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket

please apologize the unprecise title for this question, I am not an experienced programmer and even less so in node.js

My intent is a simple one: I want to use the *bitfinex-api-node* package (a node.js wrapper for bitfinex cryptocurrency exchange) that I installed via npm to read price data of various currency-pairs from the exchange to calculate better trading strategies.

The example code provided in the readme.md works fine, this is a stripped down version that creates a BFX-object which subscribes to a ticker of a given currency-pair and constantly outputs ticker-data:

```
const BFX = require('bitfinex-api-node')

const API_KEY = 'secret'
const API_SECRET = 'secret'

const opts = {
  version: 2,
  transform: true
}

const bws = new BFX(API_KEY, API_SECRET, opts).ws


bws.on('open', () => {
  bws.subscribeTicker('BTCUSD') 
})

bws.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
  console.log('Ticker:', ticker)
})

bws.on('error', console.error)
```

so far so good. Now for the sake of a simple example let's say I want to get the current price of two currency pairs (BTC/USD, ETH/USD) and add them an display the result. My obviously naive approach is like this:

```
const BFX = require('bitfinex-api-node')

const API_KEY = 'secret'
const API_SECRET = 'secret'

const opts = {
  version: 2,
  transform: true
}

const bws1 = new BFX(API_KEY, API_SECRET, opts).ws
const bws2 = new BFX(API_KEY, API_SECRET, opts).ws

var priceBTCUSD;
var priceETHBTC;

bws1.on('open', () => {
  bws1.subscribeTicker('BTCUSD') 
})
bws2.on('open', () => {
  bws2.subscribeTicker('ETHUSD') 
})

bws1.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
  //console.log('Ticker1:', ticker.LAST_PRICE)
  priceBTCUSD = ticker.LAST_PRICE
})
bws2.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
  //console.log('Ticker2:', ticker.LAST_PRICE)
  priceETHBTC = ticker.LAST_PRICE
})

bws1.on('error', console.error)
bws2.on('error', console.error)
//HERE IT COMES:
console.log(priceBTCUSD+priceETHBTC)
```

where the resulting output of the last line is "NaN". It seems the last line that logs the desired result to the console is executed before the BFX-objects establish a connection and receive any data.

How do I set this up properly? How can I retrieve data from the received data-stream? Do I really need a BFX-websocket object per currency pair? How would I read the price-data once, close down the websocket connection (which is not needed after reading the price once) and reconnect to read the price for a different currency pair?

Thank you! Feel free to request more data if my question isn't clear enough.

Kind regards,
s

Answer (score 1):

Oh, your console.log is too soon there. Try this (I skipped a few lines):

```
bws1.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
  //console.log('Ticker1:', ticker.LAST_PRICE)
  priceBTCUSD = ticker.LAST_PRICE;
  printResults();
})
bws2.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
  //console.log('Ticker2:', ticker.LAST_PRICE)
  priceETHBTC = ticker.LAST_PRICE
  printResults();
})

bws1.on('error', console.error)
bws2.on('error', console.error)
//HERE IT COMES:
function printResults() {
  if (priceBTCUSD && priceETHBTC)
    console.log(priceBTCUSD+priceETHBTC)  
}
```

Now, this is not the best approach, but it gets you of the ground. A better way is to have both prices asked on the same websocket, so when you get both prices back, call this function to calculate your results.

Comment: thanks! although this is not the full answer for the postet question it really got me rethinking my approach. Instead of having my program trying to fetch data from the websocket stream object I now 'base' my program inside the the websocket function (I hope you know what I mean, just like the example you gave) and make various calls from within. Not sure if this is the intended way to do it but for now it works! Again, thank you!

Comment: Well, you usually base your program as a set of modules. One module is designed to handle websocket communication. Incoming messages routed to proper business components. Any "clients" call this module for outgoing messages. Now, your business components, they each handle their thing. E.g. one will handle all incoming "ticker" messages. One will handle price comparisons. Etc. So you don't write the program "inside websocket". You just have a few routing functions, that, depending on what has come in, route the message to proper service or module.